# Calling the base class method from Code Quotations

Tags: f#, quotations

Let's say I have two simple classes :

```
type BaseClass() =
    abstract member PreStart : unit -> unit
    default x.PreStart() =
        printfn "Base class PreStart method"

type DerivedClass() as this =
    inherit BaseClass()

    override this.PreStart() =
        // I want to pass the body from outside
        ()
```

What I'm trying to do is to allow the scenario when one could pass an implementation body of the `DerivedClass.PreStart` method from outside. Of course I could pass just a function that could be called inside the `PreStart` method but this has some drawback related to the call of `base.PreStart()` method. I would have to pass an extra parameter to indicate whatever I want to execute the base method before the overriden body or after if at all.

What I would like to do is to allow the definition of the body like that :

```
let preStart = (fun (baseFn : unit->unit) ->
                        baseFn() // base class call before the overriden body
                        printfn "PreStart overriden"
                        baseFn() // base class call after the overriden body)
```

where `baseFn()` is a call to the base class method. This would be simple if we could pass around the delegate to `base.PreStart` call but this is not allowed by the compiler for obvious reasons.

My naive implementation with Quotations is as follows :

```
open FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation
open System.Linq.Expressions

type BaseClass() =

    abstract member PreStart : unit -> unit

    default x.PreStart() =
        printfn "Base class PreStart method"

type DerivedClass(expression : Expr<(unit -> obj) -> obj>) as this =
    inherit BaseClass()

    // this is not optimal <@@ this :> BaseClass @@> doesn't work
    let baseClinst = new BaseClass()
    let bexpr = <@@ baseClinst @@>
    let overrideExpr = expression
    let baseTy = typeof<BaseClass>
    let mthd = baseTy.GetMethod("PreStart")

    override this.PreStart() =
        let baseMthd = Expr.Call(bexpr, mthd, [])
        let combined = <@ ((%overrideExpr) (baseMthd.CompileUntyped())) @>
        let l = QuotationEvaluator.EvaluateUntyped combined
        ()

let preStart = <@ 
                    fun (baseFn : unit->obj) ->
                        baseFn() // base class call before the overriden body
                        printfn "PreStart overriden"
                        baseFn() // base class call after the overriden body
               @>

let d = new DerivedClass(preStart)
```

if prints the following output as expected:

```
> d.PreStart();;
Base class PreStart method
PreStart overriden
Base class PreStart method
val it : unit = ()
>
```

However I'm not happy with this code

- In the `DerivedClass` I have to create an instance of the base class `let baseClinst = new BaseClass()` which servs as a base expression parameter to `Expr.Call`. Doing this doesn't work `let bexpr = <@@ this :> BaseClass @@>`. This is just calling another's instance of base class retrieved by reflection.
- I had to modify the type of the function from `unit -> unit` to `unit -> obj` because of the return of the call to `baseMthd.CompileUntyped()`
- It certainly not optimal and ugly.

My question is simple. How to improve this code to be more idiomatic F#? Or maybe there are other means than Quotations to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need quotations for this. The obvious solution (that does not work) is to take a function and pass it `base.PreStart` as a parameter (so that the function can decide when to call the base class implementation):

```
type DerivedClass1(preStart) =
    inherit BaseClass()
    override this.PreStart() =
        preStart base.PreStart
```

Now, this does not work because F# only allows you to call `base.PreStart` directly and it does not allow passing it as a function. However, you can define a private `member` that calls the base class implementation and pass this new member as a parameter to `prestart`:

```
type DerivedClass(preStart) =
    inherit BaseClass()
    member private this.BasePreStart() = 
        base.PreStart()
    override this.PreStart() =
        preStart this.BasePreStart
```

Comment: Wow @Tomas, this answer is just a blast ! I've tried the first solution and because it didn't work I started to use quotations :) I didn't know that it's enough to define a level of indirection wrapping the base call and pass it to the prestart function. I didn't try as I was sure it would be a fail :) However just of curiosity if using quotations what would you fix in the original code ? Anyway it deserves a solved check :)